# macro inside tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

When I take a part of a `tikz` picture out and put it into a macro, the code
stops working.  So, why does the following not work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\emptymatrix}{%
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,
          inner sep=0pt,
          left delimiter={[},
          right delimiter={]},
          nodes={circle,inner sep=0pt}] (A) {%
    \strut & \strut & \strut & \strut \\
    \strut & \strut & \strut & \strut \\
    \strut & \strut & \strut & \strut \\
    \strut & \strut & \strut & \strut \\
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \emptymatrix
  \draw (A-1-1.center) -- (A-4-4.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Intended result:

[image]

Instead, an Undefined control sequence error occurs.

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.22   \emptymatrix
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an ampersand `&` inside a macro is not advised since it ends a group. Below is a workaround that replaces ampersands by control sequences, and then `\&` evaluates to the ampersand retro-actively. LaTeX then already evaluated the structure of your matrix to evaluate where the groups end *afterwards*. That way the structure defined by your macro doesn't break so early in the process.

The output shows this (I hope that's what you want):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/k4bbhcL.png?1]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\emptymatrix}{%
  \matrix (A) [ampersand replacement=\&,
          matrix of nodes,
          inner sep=0pt,
          left delimiter={[},
          right delimiter={]},
          nodes={circle,inner sep=0pt}] {%
    \strut \& \strut \& \strut \& \strut \\
    \strut \& \strut \& \strut \& \strut \\
    \strut \& \strut \& \strut \& \strut \\
    \strut \& \strut \& \strut \& \strut \\
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \emptymatrix
  \draw (A-1-1.center) -- (A-4-4.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```